# Using geom_raster function returns invalid 'type' (list) of argument

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-raster

I am trying to plot a matrix data into d*d grid using R. So I used `geom_raster` function.

I have data with three variables: row and col specify the location for each data point, and w is the data I wish to plot using `geom_raster`.

I simulate the three variables below:

```
row <- rep(1:55, 55)
col <- rep(1:55, 55)
w <- runif(55*55)
```

I order to use ggplot, I convert the data into dataframe form:

```
df <- data.frame(
   row = row, col = col, w = w
)
```

Now I use df to generate plot

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(row, col)) + geom_raster(fill = aes(w))
```

But it returns an error that says

> Error in stats::complete.cases(df[, vars, drop = FALSE]) :
> invalid 'type' (list) of argument

I end up do not know how to fix this bug, would anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for your `geom_raster` doesn't look right.

Try this instead:...

```
    ggplot(data = df, aes(row, col)) + geom_raster(aes(fill=w))
```